# Star Micronics TSP 650 Printer and iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am using **Star Micronics TSP 650 Printer** SDK for iOS in my application. I'm just using sample codes they have provided in the SDK sample
http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

But the question is printing take too much time (normally it takes more than 25s to print a a receipt)

I can't figure out any issue in my app. (because their sample app also take more than 25s to print a receipt)

So, is it a fault of the SDK? if anyone have work with this SDK, please give me some help.

Comment: Maybe it's your specific hardware? Does it print at full speed if you hook it up to a computer?

Comment: Yes! it's work normal with my macbook

Comment: hi. is this tsp650ii model's sdk available for ios?

Answer (score 2):

There are two versions of the ios framework. One that is optimized for airport express and one that is not. You have to get the replaced the old framework with the new one and recompile for normal printing times. If you are still having this trouble, email me at Kevans@starmicronics.com and I will send you the optimized framework